# ExtJS4: Why when I use directFn config in my store I need to specify directCfg.method as directFn's property

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Recently I was using directFn config like this:

```
var store = new Ext.data.Store({
    proxy: {
        type: 'direct',
        directFn: myDirectfn,
...
```

But it wouldn't work because ExtJS threw exception

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of undefined

at the lines

```
method = fn.directCfg.method;
if (method.ordered) {
```

in file `path/to/ext/src/data/proxy/Direct.js`. After some digging I've found out that `fn` refers to `myDirectfn` function. So I've just added lines:

```
myDirectfn.directCfg = {
    method: {}
};
```

in my code. After that all started to work properly ([Here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/TfXUM/)).

So the question is: What kind of magical thing is this `directCfg`? Why is it needed?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using `directFn` inappropriately. `directFn` has to be used in tandem with [`Ext.direct.RemotingProvider`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.direct.RemotingProvider). Check out [official example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/direct/direct-grid.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the remote method in Ext.app.REMOTING_API before in can be called.  In the [example given by reporter](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/direct/direct-grid.html), the api page is included and defines the "TestAction" function called by the proxy:

```
Ext.ns("Ext.app"); 
Ext.app.REMOTING_API = {"url":"php\/router.php","type":"remoting","actions":{"TestAction":[{"name":"doEcho","len":1},{"name":"multiply","len":1},{"name":"getTree","len":1},{"name":"getGrid","len":1},{"name":"showDetails","params":["firstName","lastName","age"]}],"Profile":[{"name":"getBasicInfo","len":2},{"name":"getPhoneInfo","len":1},{"name":"getLocationInfo","len":1},{"name":"updateBasicInfo","len":0,"formHandler":true}]}};
```

Once the direct function is defined in the Ext.app.REMOTING_API, that error should go away.