# ExtJS4 Ext.data.Store Load data from a function

Tags: javascript, extjs

Using ExtJS4 Store, I want to execute a Javascript function to return json data, ie. getMyJsonData, to load the data into the store.

```
function getMyJsonData() {
  var myjson = {... };
  return myjson;

}
```

Trawling through the doco, I can't find a way to define a callback function to load the data, all I found was a Memory Store which loads an already defined data object.

How can I call a function instead ?

```
 Ext.define('perhoo.store.Users',
        {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
            model: 'perhoo.model.User',
            autoLoad: true,


                data : {
                users: [
                    { id: 1, name: 'joe44', email: 'joe@joe.com'},
                    { id: 2, name: 'bloggs44', email: 'bloggs@joe.com'}
                    ]
            },

            proxy: {
                type: 'memory',
                data: this.data,
                reader: {
                    type : 'json',
                    root : 'users'
                }
            }
```

EDIT

The reason I want to call a function is because I want to execute LinkedIn API.
And going through Ext JSONP Proxy (as it's cross domain) makes things 10x more complicated as I have to get LinkedIn auth etc etc (which I don't know how to do it yet)

i.e.
    var mydata = null;

```
function onLinkedInAuth() {
   // Linked in api to find connections
   IN.API.Connections("me").result( function(result) { 

        mydata = result;
   } );

}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to get the data through ajax for ex?

Comment: The reason I want to call a function is because I want to execute LinkedIn API.
And going through Ext JSONP Proxy (as it's cross domain) makes things 10x more complicated as I have to get LinkedIn auth etc etc (which I don't know how to do it yet)

Comment: Have you tried to user data:yourfunction() or somthing similar?

Comment: the answer is in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873534/extjs4-why-when-i-use-directfn-config-in-my-store-i-need-to-specify-directcfg-m

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS4's store using proxy to load data, check below:

```
var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'User',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : '/users.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});
```

When executed, it reads data from the `url`, `/users.json`, and store into itself.

Also, if you want to process data yourself and load them into store yourself, you can check below:

```
//this is the model we will be using in the store
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'id',    type: 'int'},
        {name: 'name',  type: 'string'},
        {name: 'phone', type: 'string', mapping: 'phoneNumber'}
    ]
});

//this data does not line up to our model fields - the phone field is called phoneNumber
var data = {
    users: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Ed Spencer',
            phoneNumber: '555 1234'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Abe Elias',
            phoneNumber: '666 1234'
        }
    ]
};

//note how we set the 'root' in the reader to match the data structure above
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: true,
    model: 'User',
    data : data,
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users'
        }
    }
});
```

And you could easily use`setProxy` to change the behavior when you want.

Links:

- http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-method-setProxy
- http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Memory

Comment: The reason I want to call a function is because I want to execute LinkedIn API.
And going through Ext JSONP Proxy (as it's cross domain) makes things 10x more complicated as I have to get LinkedIn auth etc etc (which I don't know how to do it yet).
and i don't see how extjs4 can do this out-of-the-box, do you ?

Comment: @portoalet As far as I know, what we can do is to set an empty proxy at first and when your data is ready, use setProxy to replace the empty proxy with a well-prepared memory proxy. Also, there is a DirectProxy seems to have a function to complete the data request: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Direct

Comment: thanks, i followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873534/extjs4-why-when-i-use-directfn-config-in-my-store-i-need-to-specify-directcfg-m and now it works.